# Line spacing not working with \fontsize

Tags: spacing, fontsize, line-spacing, mathptmx

**Problem:**

Getting line-spacing to work with \fontsize. Regardless of what value I use in the second parameter, the line-spacing won't change.

**Package:**

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

**Code:**

```
\chapter{Publications}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Paper I} \\ \\ \\
{\fontsize{19}{60}\selectfont A long title of the paper here that breaks into three lines but regardless of what value I use, line-spacing does not change.\par} \\ \\
\vspace*{\fill}

\includepdf[pages=-]{Papers/campaigning.pdf}
```

**Desired solution:**

To get line-spacing for the subtitle to change.

Comment: from the first `\fontsize` to after the `\vspace*{\fill}` is all one paragraph, as you've written it -- those `\\\` don't end the paragraph.  (la)tex sets the font parameters as they're set at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: @wasteofspace Thanks, managed to solve it. Was too blind to see it myself.